# Do multiple yanks in Tmux without exiting copy mode?

Tags: tmux

## Background

I love tmux and copy mode specifically, but often I want to copy several things which may be way up my history, or I'm just scrolling through my history and want to continue scrolling where I left off even after I make a copy.

## Question

Is there any way to yank a selection without exiting copy mode?

## Other Questions

My question is analogous to this other unanswered one, but that one is for screen, not tmux: [GNU screen append buffer multiple times without exiting copy-mode](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675348/gnu-screen-append-buffer-multiple-times-without-exiting-copy-mode)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, neither `tmux` nor `screen` have any way to do this.  Yank replaces the current buffer, it doesn't append to it.

If you're running `tmux` in a terminal emulator in a desktop environment (or on the Linux console using [gpm](https://nico.schottelius.org/software/gpm/) for mouse cut/copy/paste), the easiest way to do something kind of similar to you want is to run `vim` or some other editor in another terminal and use the mouse to copy-paste text into the editor's buffer.   That's what I do.

Alternatively, save the entire buffer to a file and then use `vim` or something to edit the file to remove everything you don't want to keep.

There's also a `tmux` plugin called [tmux-yank](https://tmux-plugins.github.io/tmux-yank/) which uses `xsel` (or `xclip`, or `wl-copy`) to copy whatever you yank to the system's clipboard.  It would probably be trivial to modify it to use `xsel -a -i` instead of just `xsel -i`.   I have no idea how, I've never used `tmux-yank`, I only just discovered it by searching with https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tmux+yank&ia=web

Comment: Actually, tmux does have a list of previous yanks, so you can do CTL+B = to get that list and pick one, so it is totally conceivable that it could add a yank to that stack and get ready for another without leaving or losing your place in the copy mode. As far as I can tell none of your solutions would allow me to stay in my workflow (in copy mode) scrolling through the tmux history. Did I miss something?

Comment: 1. "totally conceivable" is not the same as "that feature already exists".  It's not even the same as "that feature is possible to implement".   If that feature does exist, then great - you have your answer.  If not, then patch tmux or write a plugin to implement it, or find a compromise that's acceptable to you.   2.  I never claimed that this answer was exactly what you asked for. In fact, I stated explicitly that it wasn't: "AFAIK, neither tmux nor screen have any way to do this." followed by (paraphrased) "here are some alternatives that may be of interest to you".

Comment: You're right, I got into the details and forgot your opening line. Thanks for confirming!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I keep the copy mode open

```
    set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send -X begin-selection
    bind-key -T copy-mode-vi V send -X select-line
-   bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe-and-cancel 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'
+   bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe 'xclip -in -selection clipboard'
```

I used the tmux vim configuration from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51639642/599743), and changed the line above from copy-pipe-and-cancel to copy-pipe

Comment: This looks like a git diff. Perhaps make it more clear that the diff is relative to the answer you linked (to help beginners who might try to copy your code as is).